# Making aysnchronous sequential circuits hazard free

Tags: digital-logic, switching, logic-hazard

The problem I am stuck with requires me design a hazard free asynchronous sequential circuit for a given problem description. I have followed the routine steps as follows:

- I have obtained the primitive flow table from the problem description
- I have reduced the flow table using state minimisation routines of incompletely specified FSM
- I have assigned the output symbol preventing glitches
- I have done the state assignments of the reduced flow table

Let us assume that I require three secondary variables \$ y_1,y_2 ,y_2 \$ for the state encoding.

Now I have the resulting flow table. I am stuck at how I should proceed for hazard checking. I know the general procedure of checking and removing static and dynamic hazards, given a function and some transitions.

In this problem,

- For static hazards, I guess, I should check the KMap for each \$y_1 ,y_2,y_3\$ and thereby check for adjacent \$1\$s. Am I right?
- For dynamic hazards, I really have no clue how to proceed. Descriptive answers would be very helpful

Comment: Just clock the outputs via d type flip-flops on the opposite edge to what made the outputs in the first place.

Comment: @Andyaka: Asynchronous means there's no clock.

Comment: *check adjacent 1s in the K-map* for sum-of products, *adjacent 0s* for POS. No dynamic hazard can occur in a circuit without static hazards.